# Disassemble components

Tags: barcode, anylogic, disassembly

I would like to simulate the disassembly of electronic components. For example, an electronic component should be disassembled into its individual parts. Afterwards it should be traceable by barcode, where the disassembled product comes from, no matter in which order parts of other electronic components are processed.

So I have an initial product, which is to be disassembled into more and more parts, which can be traced back to the same original component at the end. One idea would be to append an agent after each process step which describes where the part comes from, but I don't know if this is feasible at all.

I am still quite new to AnyLogic and therefore cannot explain a solution myself. Does anyone have an approach or an idea how to proceed here?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on *how to solve a problem*, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “how do I best do X” question. This is too broad for SOF and better asked in a forum like LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :)

Comment: @Benjamin Maybe [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) can help with a better understanding of code, patterns etc? Or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: @Benjamin  okay thanks for the hint Benjamin! I will try to improve this in the future and to specify my questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Batch` and `Unbatch` objects when using process modelling blocks.

Else, use variables to store your prior agents.